# O que são variáveis de ambiente?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variáveis-de-ambiente

Tenho visto muitas perguntas, artigos e até mesmo em alguns módulos da biblioteca padrão do Python onde é introduzido um termo que é "variáveis de ambiente". Aqui no StackOverflow tem muitas questões que falam das mesmas, mas sempre em como manipulá-las, dependente de uma determinada linguagem. Minhas dúvidas são:

- O que são variaveis de ambiente?
- Todas as linguagens possuem as mesmas?
- Quando devo usa-lás?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### O que são variáveis de ambiente?

Quando um programa é executado, ele recebe informações do ambiente em que ele está sendo executado. Essas informações de ambiente são passadas implicitamente via variáveis de ambiente. Esses valores são, por exemplo, o *locale* do sistema, tipo do terminal, etc.

Elas são valores nomeados dinamicamente no sistema operacional, que afeta o comportamentos dos programas que o consome. Elas são guardadas em uma "lista" de chave-valor.

Todos os valores das variáveis de ambiente são strings não nulas.

Geralmente, guardamos configurações nessas variáveis, tanto do usuário logado no sistema, como *system-wide*. Veja algumas variáveis de ambiente que estão configuradas no meu sistema:

```
"EDITOR"=>"vim",
"HOME"=>"/Users/vnbrs"
"LANG"=>"en_US.UTF-8"
"PAGER"=>"less"
"PWD"=>"/Users/vnbrs"
"SHELL"=>"/bin/zsh"
"SSH_KEY_PATH"=>"~/.ssh/rsa_id"
"USER"=>"vnbrs"
```

Essas configurações podem ser recuperadas pelos processos do sistema. Os sub-processos herdam as variáveis de ambiente do processo-pai.

#### Todas as linguagens possuem as mesmas?

Não é que as linguagens possuam, mas sim os processos. As linguagens de implementações de comunicação com as APIs do sistema operacional para consultá-las. Um exemplo com Python:

```
# test.py
import os
os.environ
```

E executamos no shell:

```
$ python test.py
# => { 'COLORTERM': 'truecolor', 'PAGER': 'less', ... }
```

A maioria dos shells do UNIX permitem que você injete variáveis de ambiente por programa via linha de comando, veja:

```
$ MINHA_VARIAVEL=meu_valor python test.py
# => { 'MINHA_VARIAVEL': 'meu_valor', 'COLORTERM': 'truecolor', 'PAGER': 'less', ... }
```

Note que essa variável de ambiente só estará disponível para esse processo, no caso  `python`.

#### Quando devo usa-lás?

**Chaves e senhas**

Existem vários usos das variáveis de ambiente. Um uso frequente é para guardar chaves e senhas, embora existam métodos melhores. Ao invés de você ter diversas constantes na sua aplicação para guardar chaves de API, senhas de banco de dados e essas coisas, por que não colocá-las em variáveis de ambiente?

As configurações de desenvolvimento:

```
# development.env
MYSQL_HOST=0.0.0.0
MYSQL_USER=admin
MYSQL_PASSWORD=admin

GITHUB_API_KEY=test
STACKOVERFLOW_API_KEY=test
TRAVIS_CI_API_KEY=test
```

As configurações de produção (fictícios):

```
# production.env
MYSQL_HOST=172.28.281.1
MYSQL_USER=ncuabs9123h
MYSQL_PASSWORD=asduUG&*@!Y*#BSDbis

GITHUB_API_KEY=HASDb9IHU1u2h9
STACKOVERFLOW_API_KEY=oaishdBHSDP(*IH
TRAVIS_CI_API_KEY=ASIJPNDUQH*(@#audsibu
```

Essas variáveis podem ser carregadas dinamicamente na aplicação, dependendo do ambiente. Assim, você consegue esconder as chaves, não precisando compartilhar com quem não compete essas informações.

**Configurações do sistema**

O sistema operacional e algumas aplicações utilizam das variáveis de ambiente para se localizar. Se você desenvolve em Java, deve conhecer o `JAVA_HOME`. É assim que os programas sabem onde o Java está instalado.

Para quem "vive" no terminal sabe que `cd ~` te levará ao diretório home do usuário logado. Mas de onde ele tira essa configuração? É da variável de ambiente `HOME`. No meu caso:

```
HOME=/Users/vnbrs
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: cd ~ não leva à raiz, mas sim ao diretório home do usuário logado.

Comment: poderia complementar dizendo que as variáveis de ambiente servem para o programador não se preocupar com as configurações específicas das máquinas, por exemplo, senha de banco de dados, endpoint de apis em produção, pois, isso é tarefa dos administradores da rede.